# Please help retag untagged questions

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging

Poking around on the site, I noticed that the [untagged](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag has 28 questions in it.

If you can spare a few minutes, please try to grab a few questions where you recognize the subject [from the list](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and add appropriate tag(s); this'll help folks find them more easily in the future. If a tag needs to be created for one of these questions and you don't have [the necessary privilege](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), just leave a note for me here and I'll add it.

Most of these are probably due to single-use tags that were deleted automatically after 6 months; the system will remove tags that aren't used more than once *unless someone has written a tag wiki for it*. I see that several people here have been adding such wikis for more obscure tags (for example, [closed-transfer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-transfer)) - thanks, this'll save having to re-add the tag in the future!

Comment: Is a tag wiki excerpt sufficient to avoid automatic deletion or do they need a full wiki page?

Comment: Either an excerpt *or* a full wiki will prevent culling for single-use tags, @thesquaregroot.

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through the untagged questions and addressed all of the ones I thought seemed reasonable for the site.  There are four left at this point but all ones that seems like they should be closed to me (two of them are already closed).  Is it help to re-tag these as well?

Regardless, I ended up creating the following tags in the process and suggested tag wiki excerpts for them:

- [mouthfeel](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouthfeel)
- [proteins](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proteins)
- [fruit-extract](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruit-extract)
- [sahti](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sahti)
- [session-beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/session-beer)
- [health-effects](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-effects)
- [terminology](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

Some of them (definitely [sahti](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sahti) and [terminology](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), maybe one or two others) also applied to existing questions which I edited to have those tags.

[Feel free to check my work, though,](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/12609/thesquaregroot?tab=activity&sort=revisions) in case maybe there are some better tags that could be used in some places.  I tried to use existing tags when necessary but some were definitely tough ([health-effects](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-effects) definitely took some time to think of/be okay with).

Comment: Good work! [health-effects] gives me pause, but only because that question seems a bit borderline; we may need to revisit it in the future. The rest look great! I've deleted the closed questions; this should conclude the effort.